# Constructor Chaning In Java

Tags: java, class

Java is not my strong suite, so please go easy! :)

I am trying to do *construtor-chaining* between below `super` and `sub` class

**//SuperClass**

```
class Furniture{

     String name;
     int cost;
     boolean IsAvlbl;

     void Furniture(String name,int cost,boolean IsAvlbl){
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.IsAvlbl = IsAvlbl;

     }
}
```

**//Sub-class**

```
public class Table extends Furniture{


  public Table(String name,int cost,boolean IsAvlbl)
  {
      super(name,cost,IsAvlbl);
  }


  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      Table t = new Table("dinning",2600,false);
      t.runner();
  }

  void runner()
  {
    System.out.println("Name : "+this.name);
    System.out.println("Cost : "+this.cost);
    System.out.println("Is Avaiable : "+this.IsAvlbl);
  }


}
```

Error popping up is :

> Table.java:20: error: constructor Furniture in class Furniture cannot be applied to given types;
>
> ```
>     super(name,cost,IsAvlbl);
>     ^   required: no arguments   found: String,int,boolean
> ```
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 1 error

I understand that constructor call has to be the first line and parameters have to be same....I tried doing it but error is persistent.

I would appreciate if some one can tell **me why this error** is popping up as i want to understand the cause of it..... *try it this way* kind of solution is not preferred!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor will not have any return type

it should be like

```
Furniture(String name,int cost,boolean IsAvlbl){
    this.name = name;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.IsAvlbl = IsAvlbl;

}
```

you have `void` keyword before constructor, which makes it a method. Since you had return type, java found only *"no argument" (default)* constructor in `Furniture` class, hence giving that compilation error.

Comment: damnnn....super dumb, i know the difference but i never spotted it in the code!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

In Java, constructor should not have return type. Remove `void` from `Furniture` constructor

```
Furniture(String name,int cost,boolean IsAvlbl){
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.IsAvlbl = IsAvlbl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> void Furniture(String name,int cost,boolean IsAvlbl){  // Method

is a method and not a constructor.
Replace it with :

> Furniture(String name,int cost,boolean IsAvlbl){ // Constructor

Remember, **constructors do not have return-types**. Interestingly, you can define a method with the Class-Name (similar to constructors) but the only difference is that, methods will have return-types.

Answer (score 2):

`void Furniture()` is not the constructor. It is treated as a method in your `Furniture` class.

`public Furniture()` is the proper syntax as constructors do not have any return type.

```
public Furniture(String name, int cost, boolean IsAvlbl) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.IsAvlbl = IsAvlbl;
}
```